# What's the difference between Thread.currentThread().getName() and getName()?

Tags: java, multithreading

What's the difference between the static `Thread.currentThread().getName()` and `getName()` of a particular Thread instance?

Comment: `new Thread(new Thread() { @Override public void run() { System.err.println(/***/Thread.currentThread()./***/getName()); }}).start();` will show a difference between the two. (Tips: Don't subclass unnecessarily (for instance `Thread`, `JFrame`, `JPanel`. Don't go around having classes unnecessarily implementing interfaces for the hell of it.)

Comment: Either they are from different classes, or they are the same method and there is no difference. Your question doesn't actually make any sense.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is `getName()` is an instance method, meaning it operates on an instance of the `Thread` class.

`Thread.getCurrentThread()` is a class or static method, meaning it does not operate on an instance of `Thread` but rather on its class.

The ultimate difference is this:  if you call `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, `currentThread()` will return an instance of `Thread`, which you can then call `getName()` on that instance.  You cannot call `Thread.getName()` because `getName()` has to be called on an instance of `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.currentThread().getName(...)` method refers to the name of the current thread whereas `getName(...)` refers to the name of any instance of Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

However, very much to the contrary, Thread.currentThread() returns the current Thread instance. Therefore the answer is: The two funcions are the same from the same thread. Try this one:

```
Thread nuThread = new Thread("Proba"){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(this.getName());
    Thread other = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println(other.getName());
    System.out.println(this==other ? "Same object":"Different object");
  }
};
nuThread.start();
try {
  nuThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```